# A commutative ring R is an integral domain $\iff a,b,c \in R, a \neq0, ab=ac \implies b=c$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> A commutative ring R is an integral domain $\iff a,b,c \in R, a \neq0,
> > ab=ac \implies b=c$.

I am relatively new to rings and I am struggling with shaking off the habit of taking cancellation laws of groups. So, I would like some validation for the following proof which came out to be deceptively straightforward:

($\implies$)

Let $R$ be a commutative ring which is also an integral domain. Let $a,b,c \in R$ be s.t. $a \neq 0, ab=ac$. Then $ab=ac \implies ab-ac=ac+(-ac)\implies ab-ac=0 \implies a(b-c)=0$

By hypothesis $a\neq 0$ so $b-c=0$ since $R$ is an integral domain. Hence, $b=c$.

($\impliedby$)

Let $R$ be a commutative ring s.t. the property $a,b,c \in R$ for $a \neq 0$ be s.t. $ab=ac \implies b=c$ holds.

Let $x,y \in R$ s.t. $xy=0$. $\exists p,q \in R$ s.t. $y=p+(-q)$.

Then
$$
\begin{equation}
xy = 0 \\
x(p+(-q)) =0 \\
x(p-q)=0 \\
xp-xq =0 \\
xp-xq +xq = 0+xq \\
xp=xq \implies p=q \implies (p-q) =0 \implies y=0
\end{equation}
$$
So $R$ has no zero divisors and hence, is an integral domain. $\Box$

Comment: The converseseems difficult to justify, in my opinion. $p$ and $q$ come out of nowhere and are wholly unmotivated and unjustified. Why bother? If $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$, then $xy=x0$. Go from there. (To see why they are unnecessary... what prevents you from taking $p=y$ and $q=0$)?

Comment: Hint: it's equivalent to $\ a\neq 0,\, a(b-c)=0\, \Rightarrow\, b-c = 0\ \ \ $

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see your point and I like your approach better. But for my clarification, can’t we still cook up such $p,q$ s.t. $y=p-q$? Just like in groups, we have $a\in G$, then $a=bc$ for some $b,c \in G$.

Comment: Yes, you can, which amounts to interpolating the equivalent form I gave between the two - which makes it clearer.

Comment: @Sun: Yes, you can, as I said: take $p=y$ and $q=0$. Or take $p=0$ and $q=-y$. In fact, those may be the only possible choices (e.g., in the field of $2$ elements). So, again, what is the point? You introduce two unmotivated new variables that play absolutely no *actual* role in your proof. And you don’t prove they exist (and if you do... then just use the two specific ones!).

Answer (score 1):

For the side $\Leftarrow$ I think that you prove is a little bit too much complicated :

Here is my proof :

$xy=0 \Rightarrow xy+x=x=x(y+1) $ if we assume that x is not zero then :

We can by assumption "eliminate x"

$1=y+1$

Then y is equal to zero

Comment: In my opinion, this is a little but too complicated. Easier to just say $xy=0\implies xy=x0$. Save yourself two steps.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin You right .:)